# data.table and using roll over multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I can't get my head around something that looks obvious...

```
 library(data.table)
 DT1<-data.table(MyDate=as.Date(rep("2019-02-01")),MyName=c("John","Peter","Paul"),Rate=c(210,180,190))

 DT2<-data.table(MyDate=seq(as.Date("2019-01-27"),as.Date("2019-02-03"),by="days"))
 setkey(DT1,MyDate)
 setkey(DT2,MyDate)
```

I would like to see the rate for John, Peter and Paul be rolled forward towards the end. When I do

```
DT1[DT2,on=.(MyDate),roll=TRUE]
```

I get :

```
        MyDate MyName Rate
 1: 2019-01-27   <NA>   NA
 2: 2019-01-28   <NA>   NA
 3: 2019-01-29   <NA>   NA
 4: 2019-01-30   <NA>   NA
 5: 2019-01-31   <NA>   NA
 6: 2019-02-01   John  210
 7: 2019-02-01   Paul  190
 8: 2019-02-01  Peter  180
 9: 2019-02-02  Peter  180
10: 2019-02-03  Peter  180
```

While I want this :

```
       MyDate MyName Rate
 1:  2019-01-27   <NA>   NA
 2:  2019-01-28   <NA>   NA
 3:  2019-01-29   <NA>   NA
 4:  2019-01-30   <NA>   NA
 5:  2019-01-31   <NA>   NA
 6:  2019-02-01   John  210
 7:  2019-02-01   Paul  190
 8:  2019-02-01   Peter 180
 9:  2019-02-02   John  210
 10: 2019-02-02   Paul  190
 11: 2019-02-02   Peter 180
 12: 2019-02-03   John  210
 13: 2019-02-03   Paul  190
 14: 2019-02-03   Peter 180
```

It's obvious I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficult part was the cross-join-esque rows you need after a matching date but not before that matching date. I think the steps below get at this issue.

Perform a rolling join for each Name, then change the `MyName` column around and filter for resulting unique lines.

```
library(magrittr)
DT1[, .SD[DT2, roll = TRUE], by = MyName][
      , MyName := ifelse(is.na(Rate), NA, MyName)
    ][order(MyDate, MyName), .(MyDate, MyName, Rate)] %>% 
  unique()

        MyDate MyName Rate
 1: 2019-01-27   <NA>   NA
 2: 2019-01-28   <NA>   NA
 3: 2019-01-29   <NA>   NA
 4: 2019-01-30   <NA>   NA
 5: 2019-01-31   <NA>   NA
 6: 2019-02-01   John  210
 7: 2019-02-01   Paul  190
 8: 2019-02-01  Peter  180
 9: 2019-02-02   John  210
10: 2019-02-02   Paul  190
11: 2019-02-02  Peter  180
12: 2019-02-03   John  210
13: 2019-02-03   Paul  190
14: 2019-02-03  Peter  180
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks a lot, this indeed solves my question.

Answer (score 5):

A convoluted way (found by trial and error):

```
DT1[DT2, on=.(MyDate <= MyDate), allow.cartesian = TRUE]

        MyDate MyName Rate
 1: 2019-01-27   <NA>   NA
 2: 2019-01-28   <NA>   NA
 3: 2019-01-29   <NA>   NA
 4: 2019-01-30   <NA>   NA
 5: 2019-01-31   <NA>   NA
 6: 2019-02-01   John  210
 7: 2019-02-01  Peter  180
 8: 2019-02-01   Paul  190
 9: 2019-02-02   John  210
10: 2019-02-02  Peter  180
11: 2019-02-02   Paul  190
12: 2019-02-03   John  210
13: 2019-02-03  Peter  180
14: 2019-02-03   Paul  190
```